# Prevent AdSense from warning me when my ad code appears on unauthorized sites?

Tags: google-adsense

On the advice of my AdSense optimization specialist, I enabled the [setting in Google AdSense that prevents my ads from showing up on sites that I haven't authorized](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/65062?hl=en).   This is evidentally important because your account can be revoked if the ads show up on sites that don't conform to Google's AdSense Policies.

One big downside to this is that there is a list of about 80 third party sites that show my ads.  Most of them are sites that cache my content in some form.  Now when I log into my AdSense account Google shows the message:

> We've noticed your ad code has appeared on websites you haven't authorized. To avoid lost revenue, make sure to authorize any sites you own to display ads by visiting your account settings.

Is there any way to make this message disappear other than authorizing these sites?  This alert is getting on my nerves.  I haven't been able to find a black list equivelant of Google's authorized sites white list.

[image: unauthorized AdSense sites]

Comment: Where did you get the list of unauthorized sites in Google AdSense login?

Comment: @SrihariKaranth It looks different now.   I still have some unverified sites, but they are mixed in with the verified sites.   My verified sites have a green check next to them and the unverified ones have a gray check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was [discussed on WebmasterWorld](http://www.webmasterworld.com/google_adsense/4275571.htm) in 2011 where [AdSenseAdvisor](http://www.webmasterworld.com/profilev4.cgi?action=view&member=AdSenseAdvisor) (a Google representative) says:

> When using the authorized sites feature, any sites that you haven't authorized will trigger an error and a message. Note that we currently consider any framed or cached pages to be unauthorized, this includes when a user searches for your site from Google Images for example and your site displays via frame. We encourage you to add these framed or cached URLs to your authorized sites list. We're investigating ways to improve this feature.

So it would appear that you could authorize the Yahoo, Google and Bing sites and not worry too much about account penalties.   If you do authorize sites, it can take a week before they drop off that list [according to the Google Product forums](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/adsense/eazfVId0ZI0/f43KwZy62SYJ). That would take the size of my list down to about 4 other sites which appear to be fairly spammy.

Unfortunately, in the last three years there don't appear to be any improvements to this feature that would prevent the warning from showing up every day when are are spam sites in this list.

### Update

As of November 2014, I don't always see this warning anymore.  If I do have the warning, the majority of the problematic sites have been removed.   Right now there is only one site in the list:

[image: unauthorized site]

Comment: Where can I see this unauthorized sites lists in Adsense?